# Get write_secure_settings without using adb command

Tags: android

How to get write_secure_settings permission for android application programmatically without using adb command for non system apps

Tried below code to get write_secure_settings permission, but not working and didn't give any request permission popup,

```
requestPermissions(this,arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of secure settings is that apps can't write it.  You need to be a system app to get it.  Meaning you can do it with a rooted device if its for personal use, but you're not getting it for a plat store app.